# Align divs with different content inside wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I have grid of divs wrapped in other div. For some reason, when content of any grid div is not the same length or type compared to other divs, grid starts to act pretty weird and those divs pops out of place.

I tried align them with `margin: 0 auto` and `text-align: center` as recommended in similar questions, but issue seems not to be resolved at all. Any tips will be appreciated.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: white;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.column.middle {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
    text-align:center;
}

.column.side {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.cells {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .column.side, .column.middle {   
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .topnav a {
        float: none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column side">
          <div>
            <p>Side column left</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="column middle">
            <div class="main">
              <div class="cells">1</div>
              <div class="cells">2</div>
              <div class="cells"></div>
              <div class="cells">4</div>
              <div class="cells"><p>5</p></div>
              <div class="cells">6</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column side">
          <div>
            <p>Side column right</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set  the `vertical-align` property on the `.cells` class:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: white;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column.middle {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.column.side {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cells {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  /* margin-top: 20px; */
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .column.side,
  .column.middle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Header Placeholder</h2>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <a href="#">2</a>
  <a href="#">3</a>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    <div>
      <p>Side column left</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column middle">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="cells">1</div>
      <div class="cells">2</div>
      <div class="cells"></div>
      <div class="cells">4</div>
      <div class="cells">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cells">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column side">
    <div>
      <p>Side column right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. May i ask why `vertical-align` should equals `top`? Does this mean that cell is aligned relative to the top element or top border?

Comment: It's doesn't have to. Middle may work as well. But the default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline which is causing your issue